# Ruby on Rails - showing all instances in a view, with specific column value, returned by other table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, web, sqlite

First, my schema looks like this:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.text     "name"
t.text     "slug"
end

create_table "fields", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "order"
t.string   "title"
t.text     "tipo"
t.text     "values"
t.integer  "sub_category_id"
end
add_index "fields", ["sub_category_id"], name: "index_fields_on_sub_category_id"

create_table "sub_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "category_id"
t.text     "name"
t.text     "slug"
end
add_index "sub_categories", ["category_id"], name: "index_sub_categories_on_category_id"
```

This is my schema, a category has many sub_categories, and a sub_category has many fields. Im trying to generate a view which contains all fields of a specific sub_category, i've already passed the sub_category.id to this view, but thats all i could do.

Its not that difficult i imagine, but im a begginer on rails. How can i do it? The routes are also a problem, since i have to create a new controller function. But the route generated by my application already looks like this:
**"/sub_categories/mysubcategory56/visualizeform?sub_category=56"**

Comment: Are you trying to render sub_category's show action? If so do post your view. You'll probably have to do a sub_category.fields.each something along those lines.

Comment: thanks man, i worked it out. Now im having problems generating the forms themselves based on table fields values. I'm trying to differentiate the types of inputs like text_field, text_area, check_box inside a helper, im using a case-when structure and html += but when i call like f.text_field inside the helper, i get an undefined method text_field error like. What do u suggest?

Comment: Its much easier to help you by seeing the actual code than a description of it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making a for on each table?  or try

```html
<%= for category.sub_category.each do |subcateg| %>
  #for getting all subcategories of a category
  <%= for subcateg.fields.each do |fields| %>
  #for getting al fields in every category and printing them
 <%= fields.order %>
 <%= fields. title %>
 <%= fields.tipo %>
 <%= fiels.values %>
 <%= fields.sub_category_id %>
```